# get the absolute path of the directory containing the ngxin configuration file in nginx configuration file

Tags: python, configuration, nginx, uwsgi

I use `nginx` + `uwsgi` to deploy my wsgi app. And I have to use the unix sock file for the communication of nginx and uwsgi.

The configuration as bellow:

```
location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/path/to/uwsgi.sock;
}
```

But the parent path of my project is mutable, So I can not use a fixed absolute path.
And I also can not use a relative path. Because the `pwd` is mutable too.

So I wander is there any variables in nginx configuration file such as `$hostname` that can point to the absolute path of the derectory containing the nginx configuration file. But I found no such a variable.

Any good ideas?

PS: I alse don't want use the socket such as `0.0.0.0:8000` for commucation of nginx and uwsgi. And the user run server is not a root user. I wanna put the socket file in the project directory.

Comment: Why can't you store the UNIX socket(s) in a standard location like ``/var/run`` or ``/tmp`` like other UNIX socket servers do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm not expert with nginx*, However;

My recommendation is to use a standard UNIX approach and store your UNIX sockets in either one of two standard locations:

- `/var/run`
- `/tmp`

If storing UNIX Sockets for users I would store them in:

- `$HOME/var/run` -- And document this to your users.

This is similar to how Apache's userdir option works by serving up files from `/home/prologic/public_html` for requests to `GET ~/prologic` for example.

Comment: In the mathin  the `/tmp` would be clean regularly. And the user run the server is not a root user. And I don't want to put the UNIX socket under the home directory.

Comment: You did not specify that the UNIX socket servers are being run by users :) What's wrong with storing them in their home directory anyway? It would be similar to how Apache's userdir option works for e.g: ``~/prologic`` serving files up from ``/home/prologic/public_html``

Comment: thanks, I inspired by you, and pass a $ROOT_DIR to the nginx configuration file.